# Build error after executing Huawei Unity SDK Setup

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk, push, onesignal, huawei-mobile-services

When following documentation for Huawei Unity SDK Setup, unable to build apk from Unity due to build errors

Link to Huawei Unity SDK Setup: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/huawei-unity-sdk-setup

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Settings file 'D:\UnityProjects\TestOSAGProject\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\settings.gradle' line: 50
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Gradle'.
D:\UnityProjects\TestOSAGProject\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\OneSignalConfig\agconnect-services.json

I already wrote to OneSignal support, but they respond very slowly, maybe there are those who met with a similar problem when working with a bunch of Unity, OneSignal and Huawei, I would be very grateful for any help

That's what I did:

1. Created a new 2D project in Unity 2021.3.22
2. Installed the OneSignal SDK for Unity according to the Unity SDK Setup instructions
3. Compiled the project, the assembly was successful
4. Set up SDK according to Huawei Unity SDK Setup instructions
5. I tried to compile the project for verification and it did not assemble, errors appeared

I expected that the project will be successfully built and everything will work